# Debug video stream in Firefox dev tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to debug a video stream using the Firefox dev tools? Specifially I would like to monitor the transfer rate and find out why a video sometimes stutters. Not sure if it is caused by the server internet connection, client internet connection or client CPU/GPU decoding the stream.

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox 87, video streams and other requests are unfortunately not shown until they are finished. There is [a bug filed to allow inspecting the data](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673562) while the requests are still in progress.